PWA installed on Android shows "Choose browser" system modal
do someone know why my PWA works after install on Android via Chrome for example for few days and someday it asks users to choose browser (via system popup/modal) and after selecting it it shows blank page?
My manifest contains name, short_name, description, icons (with src, sizes, type), start_url, display (fullscreen), theme_color and background_color.
Service worker contains only fetch, push and notificationclick event listeners.
The weird is that after re-install it works, but after some time it asks to choose browser and after choose it stops on blank screen.
EDIT:
Weird thing is that after restart of the phone everything is working.

Relevant Reddit thread. Sounds like this is an Android "feature" and not a bug, and also not actually programming-related.

Yeah, I saw that thread, but there's no informations about the reason of that behavior and when I searched that thing in the Internet, PWA-related docs etc. I didn't found any solution of that issue and also I didn't found any informations about the reason of that.
I posted question here, because maybe someone had this issue and figured it out and maybe it's service-worker related :/
